# AngularStrap popover on anchor

Tags: angularjs, anchor, popover, angular-strap

I want to use AngularStrap Popover to trigger a popover from a text element.
Is it possible to trigger a popover from an anchor? Or a span element or such?

This works:

```
<button content="hello" trigger="focus" bs-popover>clickme</button>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<a href="" content="hello" trigger="focus" bs-popover>clickme</a>
<span href="" content="hello" trigger="focus" bs-popover>clickme</span>
<label href="" content="hello" trigger="focus" bs-popover>clickme</label>
<small href="" content="hello" trigger="focus" bs-popover>clickme</small>
```

I can't find an example of how to do it was an anchor - and neither whether it is possible or not.
(span element any other lablelike element would also go, but no button .....)
Seems like a quite stupid question to me, but I really couldn't find an proper answer :/

Thanks very much!

Comment: Does nobody got any idea? Or is this actually too easy and I'm simply blind to get it? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `trigger='focus'` works for focusable elements; button is focusable, anchors and spans are not. Try `trigger='hover'`, or `trigger='click'`
You can check my plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/4oi1ucgQa6zqhQSlVhzu

Comment: Sounds promising, I will test it when home. But I remember slithly that something didn't work with `click`, I'll see ...

Comment: Works, dunno why I didn't tried it that way. I think at that time I wanted to have the effect of focus which is: click it (it appears), click somewhere else, it disappears. Which I now don't want anymore, so click suits me well.
But just out of curiosity: How would I do it if I want the above behavior? As trigger="focus" won't work? Would I need to implement it on myself, that when I click somewhere else it will disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the tab index on your anchor tag like so:

```
<a tabindex="0" href="" content="hello" trigger="focus" bs-popover>clickme</a>
```

See [this discussion](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3687) and [this analysis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Clicking_and_focus) of clicking / focusing on anchor tags in different browsers.